# Azure Front Door Visual Studio Remote Debugging

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door, azure-waf

When connecting to my Azure Web App protected by Azure WAF/FrontDoor, I cannot connect to the debugger, it seems like inbound port 4024 is blocked on the WAF/FronDoor. Remote debugging is enabled and outbound ports are open on the dev server. Any idea if this should be working or how to get this working?

Thanks.

Full error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named '***.**'.  The Visual Studio 2019 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.
> at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Operations.IDebuggerInternal120.ConnectToServer(String szServerName, VsDebugRemoteConnectOptions[] pConnectOptions, CONNECT_REASON ConnectReason, Int32 fIncrementUsageCount, IDebugCoreServer3& ppServer)
> at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Operations.RemoteDiagnosticsSessionBase`1.ConnectToServer(String site, String user, String password)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **64-bit** you must enable the port `4025`. For **32-bit** you must enable the port `4024`.

I also had this problem. I solved it by changing the Platform from 32-bit to 64-bit. Go to **App Service** -> **configuration** -> **General Settings**. Now change the Platform from `32-bit` to `64 bit`.

[image]

Refer here for [remote debugger port assignments vs 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments?view=vs-2019) & [configure the windows firewall for remote debugging vs 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging?view=vs-2019)

Refer for more  [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging?view=vs-2019)